# How to handle authentication token string in Grape API and token_and_options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, authorization, ruby-grape, ember-simple-auth

I'm using `Ember` front-end with `Grape` API and to authenticate a page I have something like:

```
  def current_user
    return nil if headers['Authorization'].nil?

    @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(
      headers['Authorization']
    )
  end
```

At the moment I'm using `ember-simple-auth` which sends something like as a header:

```
Token token="n2Rs5tokenLH", email="my@email.com"
```

Check out the Grape logger:

```
  User Load (38.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'Token token="n2Rs5tokenLH", email="my@email.com"' LIMIT 1
```

Now in rails I usually use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` to handle this. and I don't want to handle this manually using stuff like `gsub` or regular expressions. What is the best way to handle this in Grape?

Please note that the Grape API is mounted inside a rails project and inside `app/api/backend/v1/default.rb`:

```
module Backend
  module V1
    module Defaults
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do
        version 'v1', using: :path
        format :json
        prefix :api

        rescue_from :all do |e|
          Backend::Base.logger.error e
        end

        helpers do
          def current_user
            return nil if headers['Authorization'].nil?

            @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(
              headers['Authorization']
            )
          end

          def authenticate!
            error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edit:

I just found out that I can use `ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.token_and_options` to do the job, however I'm not sure how should I include this in `Grape` project.

The structure of the app looks like:

```
⇒  tree app/api
app/api
└── backend
    ├── base.rb
    └── v1
        ├── defaults.rb
        └── ....
```

I tried to include `ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token` in `defaults.rb`something like:

```
helpers do
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token

  def current_user
    return nil if headers['Authorization'].nil?

    @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(
      token_and_options(headers['Authorization'])
    )
  end

  def authenticate!
    error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
  end
end
```

But now I'm getting:

```
 undefined method `authorization' for #<String:0x007ff51cdb85f8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a customized `token_and_options` function which looks like:

```
  def token_and_options(auth_string)
    if header = auth_string.to_s[/^Token (.*)/]
      values = $1.split(',').
        inject({}) do |memo, value|
          value.strip!
          key, value = value.split(/\=\"?/)
          value.chomp!('"')
          value.gsub!(/\\\"/, '"')
          memo.update(key => value)
        end
      values.delete("token")
    end
  end
```

And then parse token with something like: `token_and_options(headers['Authorization'])`

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right path: use [token_params_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html#method-i-token_params_from) and pass in the Authorization header directly.

```
helpers do
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token

  def current_user
    return nil if headers['Authorization'].nil?

    @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(token)
  end

  def token
    token_params_from(headers['Authorization']).shift[1]
  end

  def authenticate!
    error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
  end
end
```

The `undefined method` exception is due to [token_and_options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html#method-i-token_and_options) expecting a  ActionDispatch::Request object where you're providing a String.